# Python "clear" data from socket - Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, sockets, networking, pygame, send

I have a simple server that handles player coordinates on a game that I am making. However if I set the server to send coordinates faster that every 0.5 seconds this is sent.

```
"[[0,(0,0)],[0,(0,0)]]""[[0,(0,0)],[0,(0,0)]]"
```

Is there a way to "clear" the data in the socket before the server attempts to send again?

This doesn't work either

```
 s.send("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is over TCP, right? TCP provides a reliable byte stream, but *no message boundaries*.  So you should *never* rely on TCP delivering data to the receiver in the same "chunks" in which the sender sends it.

In this case, I suspect that you're observing the effect of the "Nagle algorithm" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm), an old optimization in TCP that collapses small writes.  You could turn that off at the sender using the TCP_NODELAY socket option, and then maybe your test program would make it seem as if the problem was solved.  But in a fundamental way, it's not! It can always happen that TCP decides to deliver the bytes in chunks that are different from what is sent.

With TCP, you should always use some sort of framing to separate messages.  Alternatively, you could use a message-oriented transport such as UDP or SCTP, but those have other problems.  Or, you use a higher-level message queueing system (ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, etc.).